# Active Directory - Proxy for another employee?

Tags: active-directory

Is there a way to have Employee A be placed in Employee B's group *temporarily* while Employee B is, say, out sick? Is there a way to set an expiration of some sort so that Employee A could work on behalf of Employee B (with higher privelages) and then automatically be removed from the group when the expiration date arrives?

Answer (score 5):

There is no built-in facility to do this. You could write a script to do it, or use scheduled task to kick off a script to do it. Or just write it down on a sticky note and have a peon do it manually.

Comment: I would also note that removing them from the group as the specified time might not invalidate their security tokens, so you'd also want to force them to logout.

Comment: Haha, I like your sticky note option.

Answer (score 1):

Technically it is not possible. AD administrators can move user from one group to another but there is no such inbuilt functionality in AD to place moved users automatically to their original group. You have to do it manually every time. I am not sure about the 3rd party active directory management tools if they provide such kind of functionality. I would suggest please check some 3rd party tools if they be able to do this task. Below I am giving URLs of some 3rd party tools for your reference.

http://www.netwrix.com/group_policy_auditing_change_reporting_freeware.html

http://www.jijitechnologies.com/

You can try these and look if any of these can help you out.